# How to access mail in an organized manner

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email

I just finished setting up postfix on my ubuntu 14.04 server, however, to access my mail I have to use command line.

How can I make it so that I can access the mail in an organized manner, like through a client. Alternatively, is it possible to forward mail I get on the server to a gmail account?

Thanks.